# acmp.ru задача, python

Tags: python

Проблема не в логике кода а в ее упорядоченности, другими словами я написал как сделать ту или иную функцию, мне нужно чтобы он выводил правильно так, как просят на сайте acmp.ru, единственная моя проблема в том что я не понимаю принцип работы входных и выходных файлов, хоть убейте, пытаюсь как нибудь подстроиться под условия принятия файла в зеленый цвет, вот собственно этот код:

```
r = open('INPUT.txt', 'r')
n = r.read(1)
w = open('OUTPUT.txt', 'w')
v = 0
for i in range(0, int(n)+1, 1): #думаю здесь и обьяснять то нечего
    v += i
w.write(str(v))
```

Казалось бы, вот и простая истина, ну если закинуть это решение на сайт, бог знает какой компилятор его отвергнет, да и приплюнет на последок. И вот базовые условия для "корректной" формулировки кода:

> Требуется посчитать сумму целых чисел, расположенных между числами 1 и
> N включительно.
>
> Входные данные В единственной строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записано
> единственное целое число N, не превышающее по абсолютной величине 10000000.
>
> Выходные данные В единственную строку выходного файла OUTPUT.TXT нужно
> вывести одно целое число — сумму чисел, расположенных между 1 и N
> включительно.

Благодарю заранее, за помощь, ибо уверен в том что бравые программисты мне помогут выпутаться из клоаки дерьма поливающегося на мои плечи, и глубоко надеюсь на вашу отзывчивую и понимающую душу.

Comment: Открытые файлы надо закрывать. Ну или использовать конструкции, которые их автоматически закрывают. И вы пишете очень много лишних слов, сквозь них очень тяжело продираться до сути вопроса. Извините.

Comment: Пожалуйста, будьте добры, попробуйте мне скинуть собственный код, который работает безупречно на сайте, понимаю большое количество бессвязного текста повергло вас в смятенье, но поймите, я ведь скинул условия задачи, и подал наводящий сайт, источник моих душевных проблем. Я хочу чтобы вы скинули просто пример кода идеально взаимодействующий с входными и выходными файлами, и только тогда я буду успокоен.

Comment: если вы меня не так поняли, зайдите лучше на сайт, увидеть собственными глазами проще, чем воображать чужими

Answer (score 1):

1. Надо читать не 1 байт, а строку.
2. <s>Надо прочитанное превратить в число.</s>
3. Используй `with` для работы с файлами.
4. Там ведь наверняка есть пример, как надо писать.
5. Всё равно этот код по времени не пройдёт.

---

Кстати, можно в начале файла написать

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open('input.txt', 'r') 
sys.stdout = open('output.txt', 'w')
```

и дальше пользоваться обычными `input` и `print`

Comment: мне нужен код, не обьяснение,практически каркас под который я буду опираться. На мою дубовую голову ваши обьяснения как пустой звук, не пройдут.

Comment: и прочитанный номер под переменной n, я конвертировал на int(n) на 5 строчке, не видно что-ли? или у меня глючит? я ведь сюда и пишу чтобы пример узнать, будь он на сайте, я бы давно щеголял бы по сложным задачам, единственное что меня останавливает так это входные и выходные данные, впрочем если не понятно, зайдите на сайт, и попробуйте там помучаться

Comment: @Aizel, ok, предложил вариант.